# How do I insert the current filename into the contents in Vim?

Tags: vim

After some searching, I got to know `:echo @%` displays the current filename in the bottom line of vim-screen.

I would like to dump the filename (with and without full path) into the contents of the file without leaving `vim`.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The current filename is in the `"%` register, so you can insert it (while in insert mode) with `<c-r>%`; the full path can be inserted with `<c-r>=expand("%:p")`. You could make a macro of it if you use it often.  For more, similar tricks, see `:h expand` and `:h "=`.

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading that, but isn't `<c-r>` mapped as the redo command?

Comment: In insert mode, `<c-r>` specifies that the next character is a register.

Comment: Righto, thanks. Totally forgot to switch to insert mode...

Comment: You can also do `"%p` in normal or visual modes.

Answer (score 44):

I'm sure there are other ways to do this... but the main command you want is `:r[ead]` which inserts the output of a command into the buffer.

So, to insert just the file name:

```
:r! echo %
```

And, to include the full path:

```
:r! echo %:p
```

For more info:

```
:help read
:help filename-modifiers
```

Answer (score 22):

As can be seen in `:h registers`, the `"%` register contains the current file name. The `:pu[t]` command inserts the content of a register into the text.

So, to insert the actual filename you can type either of these, in command mode:

```
:put %
```

or

```
"%p
```

To insert the filename with the full path, type

```
:put=expand('%:p')
```

in command mode.

---

More info:

```
:h pu[t]
```

By typing `"rp` you can paste the contents of register `"r`.

Comment: The `:put "%:p"` doesn't seem to work for me. It seems to work only with *expand()*, like in: `:put =expand('%:p')`, which makes it not much less cumbersome than `<c-r>=expand('%:p')` unfortunately.

Comment: @akavel You're correct, I'll update the answer. Thank you! ;) And, indeed, both are equally verbose.

Answer (score 9):

A simple way is to run:

```
!!echo %
```

- `!!` is replacing the current line with the result of the command following it.
- `%` is replaced by the name of the edited file in the command so this will effectively insert that name in the edited file.

The filename is the one you passed to the vi(m) command and might contain a relative or absolute path. Should you want to strip it and only retain the file name, run

```
!!basename %
```

Comment: My filename contained spaces, so it was necessary for me to use `"%"` in place of just `%` - I wanted to run a command from inside vim, passing the filename as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to do this frequently, it might be useful to bind a key sequence to what you want, as per http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_current_filename

> inserts the current filename without the extension at the cursor position, when you are in insert mode.
>
> ```
> :inoremap \fn <C-R>=expand("%:t:r")<CR>
> ```
>
> To keep the extension use:
>
> ```
> :inoremap \fn <C-R>=expand("%:t")<CR>
> ```
>
> To insert the absolute path of the directory the file is in use:
>
> ```
> :inoremap \fn <C-R>=expand("%:p:h")<CR>
> ```
>
> To insert the relative path of the directory the file is in use:
>
> ```
> :inoremap \fn <C-R>=expand("%:h")<CR>
> ```

The above all work directly in `vim` for the session, or you can put it in the `.vimrc` (where the leading colon on the line is optional).

Answer (score 3):

I was googling a simplest way to insert current file name (without path or extension) to current position (no new line, no replace current line). So combining previous answers and [this link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_current_filename), this is what I was looking for.

In **insert** mode:

```
<C-R>=expand("%:t:r")
```

Then next time (with the command already in history):

```
<C-R>=<UP>
```